# Does Google read a CodeIgniter view displayed as a sitemap?

Tags: codeigniter-2, xml-sitemap

I have created a view that displays a sitemap with codeigniter when you access into www.domain.com/sitemap.xml, but there is any real sitemap.xml file.

My question is if google will read this or if i need to create a real sitemap.xml file on my site.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use Google webmaster tools

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/158587?hl=en

Here you find a function (fetch as google) where you can see your page in the way google see it.